# How serve files in folder with case insensitive on linux with nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, case-insensitive

I'm having a little problem. I need serve files with case insensitive for a folder, i use nginx:

Original:
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/b/t/bt2501_brandy.jpg
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/p/r/PR3027GUN_1.JPG

This picture above would works with this way (case insensitive):
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/b/t/BT2501_BRANDY.jpg or
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/b/t/bt2501_Brandy.jpg or
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/b/t/bt2501_Brandy.JPG
https://example.com/media/catalog/product/p/r/pr3027gun_1.JPG

Some idea for me?

I know linux is case sensitive. But i can deal with this with nginx?

Thanks

Comment: not sure about nginx, but with apache `mod_spelling` can help wtih case sensitivity issues

Comment: `mod_speling` is also a horrible security hole. The proper solution would be to fix the links in the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~* ^/media/catalog/product/ {
    # The tilde and asterisks ensure that this location will
    # be matched case insensitive. nginx does not support
    # setting absolutely everything to be case insensitive.
    # The reason is easy, it's costly in terms of performance.
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this helps on matching paths on the filesystem. AFAIK the `location` directive is only for configurations in that path, isn't it?